# Color overlaying algorithm

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing, sdk, vision

I'm looking for an algorithm to overlay a color on top of existing picture. Something similar to the following app (wall painter): http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wall-painter/id396799182?mt=8

I want a similar functionality so I can paint walls in an existing picture and change them to a different color.

I can work both in yuv or rgb mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully paint the walls in a picture, you have to do two steps:

1. Find the boundary of the wall within the picture (select the part of the image to be colored)
2. Apply the desired color to the selected area

The first step is the hard part. It similar to what Photoshop's magic wand tool would do. And indeed a search for *magic wand algorithm* turns up a few good articles such as this [article](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/) with Objective-C code.

The second step is much easier and can be achieve with `CGContextSetBlendMode` and `CGContextDrawImage`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try drawing into a graphics context with `kCGBlendModeColor`. From the documentation:

> Uses the luminance values of the background with the hue and saturation values of the source image. This mode preserves the gray levels in the image. You can use this mode to color monochrome images or to tint color images.

Experimenting with other blend modes might also do the trick. See the documentation for details (search for "kCGBlendMode").

Comment: I am overlaying 3 images and blend their colors.It does not seem to work. I have a UIView subclass with a UIImageView. I instantiate 3 of these UIViews and add them to the parent view. In the subclass drawRect I call CGContextSetBlendMode(context, self.blendMode); and CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.imageView.image.CGImage); where the lowest view uses normal blendmode and the middle and top views use multiply.I just get the top image showing. Should these all be rendered in the same context? I would like to be able to animate these layered images individually, retaining the blend modes.

Comment: Blend modes only apply within the same view. The blend mode in one view's `drawRect:` method does not influence how it blends with views below it (the `alpha` property does). You would have to draw the three images all into the same view.

Answer (score 1):

The RGB and YUV color models are not really great for changing colors in this way. I think the best color model for this is HLS.

Link: [RGB to HLS and HLS to RGB conversion source code](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c)

- H (hue) will change the base color
- L (luminance) will change the brightness
- S (saturation) will change the amount of color

You can evaluate the effect of these three components in a photo editing app, like Photoshop of The GIMP.