# Image processing - How detect array similar colors from a image on ios

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a area of similar colors when user touches into a point on imageview. Who knows library or technique to resolve problems for ios.

Original image link:

http://cannshine.com/images/1.jpg

After touched by user, link:

http://cannshine.com/images/2.jpg

Please helping, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to create a magic wand tool, correct? I can't help you come up with a way to handle this and I don't know of any libraries that can select a group of like-colored pixels based on tolerance, but there is [this article here I found](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/). It covers implementing a magic wand tool using Objective-C. I found it in the [answer to this similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456148/color-overlaying-algorithm).

Comment: It's so helpful for me. Thanks you very much!

Comment: @congtue85 You're welcome. If my answer helps you implement the tool, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to the left. :)

Comment: I've found opencv framework. Can i use this one to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCV but it might be of some use. I'd think that a Magic Wand tool could be implemented without using a third party framework, though.